# default_type application/octet-stream in nginx.conf file

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

In the default nginx configuration file i see that the default_type is set to application/octet-stream. I understand the MIME types but I do not understand why we are setting a default type. What is the significance of this configuraion? Can someone help me to understand this?

include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `default_type` **only** applies to file extensions that have not been defined in the `mime.types` file.

If the file extension is missing from the `mime.types` file, it's fairly safe to assume `application/octet-stream`, which most browsers will treat as a binary file and download it rather than attempting to render it.

The `mime.types` file is simply a `types` directive with a long list of common MIME types and their associated file extension(s).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) for details.